# reemplazar este simbolo 'Nº' por No

Tags: php, mysql

tengo este query:

> tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set nombre = replace(nombre, 'Nº',
>   'No.')");

Pero si la tabla contiene esto:

```
Nº150
Nº360
Nº458
```

No lo reemplaza, solo se ejecuta si el campo Nº esta como palabra completa

Ejemplo

Nº 45 lo cambia por No. 45 (Porque tiene un espacio en blanco)

como tengo que hacer la consulta para que tome esta consideracion y haga el cambio en todo lo que contenga Nºxxx por No.xxx

por que no esta solo el campo Nº

Comment: No será el carácter que estas utilizando para el update? Realice una prueba con los datos y a mí me actualiza bien. La prueba lo dejo en la sección de respuestas, espero te sirva para encontrar una solución. Saludos!

Comment: @ivan ¿puedes pegar el resultado de ejecutar describe tabla; donde tabla es el nombre de la tabla que estés usando? Puede que tengas algún problema de encoding o collation y no te esté cogiendo el símbolo º.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hice la siguiente prueba desde la línea de comandos:

Cree una tabla para almacenar los nombres

```
 mysql create table a(nombre varchar(20));
 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Registre los nombres según la pregunta:

```
mysql insert into a values('Nº150');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into a values('Nº360');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into a values('Nº458');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from a;
+-------+
|nombre |
+-------+
| Nº150 |
| Nº360 |
| Nº458 |
+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Ejecuté el update:

```
mysql> update a set nombre=replace(nombre, 'Nº', 'No.');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from a;
+--------+
|nombre  |
+--------+
| No.150 |
| No.360 |
| No.458 |
+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Como se puede apreciar se actualiza correctamente.